# Allinging buttons issue

Tags: css

i have 5 buttons, i need them to be in a certain order:
button 1
button 2 button 3
button 4 button 5

width wise i want button 1 to be 90% of the width and in the middle (5% blank, 90% button, 5% blank)
the rest of the buttons be 40% with 10% between 2&3 and 4&5 (also in the middle, with %5 blank on the sides)

height wise i want button 1 to take 25% (above it i want 25% of clear space)
the rest of buttons be 15% each
and between each line 5% (and 10% between last line and end of screen)
so its like:
(25% empty, 25% button 1, 5% empty, 15% buttons 2&3, 5% empty, 15% button 4&5, 10% empty)

i got wayyyyy wayyy lost in the way
any help would be much appriciated!

that is what i got so far:  [here](https://tinyurl.com/pukjmkq)
and here's an example of what i want to achieve  http://s2.postimg.org/p57abzzq1/btns.jpg
thanks!

Comment: button 1 is on top.  
button 2 and 3 are below it but on the same level.  
button 4 and 5 are below them but on the same level as well.

Comment: Please include at least some html

Comment: yes of course, forgot to attach what i did

Comment: yes please, indlude your code in jsfiddle

Comment: thats what i got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/3bmSP/1/

i know its nothing but i'm new to this and trying to get by.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to all of your specific sizing requirements, but as far as getting the buttons in the order you need, this might help:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bmSP/3/)**

I modified your html a bit since you were missing closing `</button>` tags, and had errant `</a>` tags. I also added a wrapping element, and turned it blue so you can see what is going on.

*EDIT* - Here is the updated code to style things a little closer to what you're looking for. With the buttons now set in % they should keep that layout no matter what size you set the `button-wrapper` to.

HTML:

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="btn1">button 1</button>
    <button class="btn23">button 2</button>
    <button class="btn23">button 3</button>
    <button class="btn45">button 4</button>
    <button class="btn45">button 5</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    background: lightblue;
}
.button-wrapper button:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px;
}
button {
    width: 49%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks! why did you use a wrapper for tho?
and i meant something like this:
http://s2.postimg.org/p57abzzq1/btns.jpg

Comment: @user2105849, Thanks for the clarifying image. I've updated my answer to better fit with it. I used a wrapping element to better control the buttons with css, and also to set a width that isn't the entire window width.

Comment: you thank me for clarifying?? i THANK YOU big time for this great answer! WOW! thanks a million!
now i will try to learn from it :)

Comment: @user2105849, no problem. If this solved your issue be sure to accept the answer. It gives me a slight bump, but more importantly will help future users who encounter a similar issue.